# Replace special charachter '&acute;' in C

Tags: c

I have a string to parse and it maybe contains the symbol "& acute;" depends on user data. So i want to eliminate this symbole and replace it with '.
Example :

Before --> Won´t Get Fooled Again
After  --> Won't Get Fooled Again

This is my try but it dosen't work in any way ..

```
int main()
{

  char* permenant="Won&acute;t Get Fooled Again";
  char* s=permenant;
  for ( ; *s && *s != '&'; s++) ;
  printf("found '&' character \n"); // ---> OK
  printf("s=%s \n",s);              // ---> OK
  if (*(s+1) == 'a' && *(s+2) == 'c' && *(s+3) == 'u' && *(s+4) == 't'  && *(s+5) == 'e'  && *(s+6) == ';') // ---> OK
  {
     *s='\'';   //---> NO also if *s='a'; segmentation fault !!
     while(*(s+7)!='\0')
     {
          *(s+1)=*(s+7);
          s++;
          printf("the next character is -> %c \n", *(s+7));
     }// ---> Segmentation fault also if i remove *s='\''

   }
  printf("permenant=%s \n",permenant);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Did you consider using the `strstr()` function?

Comment: Notice that in C `&acute;` is not a *single* character. You might confuse with HTML encoding. See http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: You're crashing because you're trying to modify a string literal.

Answer (score 3):

You are using string literal, which is `const char`, so you cannot modify it.

You can change it to

```
char permenant[]="Won&acute;t Get Fooled Again";
```

It will generate an array of `char`s initialized with the literal string's characters.

Side note: the `s` pointer is totally useless. You can perform your checks on `permanent` directly.

Comment: I'm working on a company  middleware existing code so if i need to add code in some place I need to be coherent to the existant. Thank u for the advice.

Comment: @W.draoui So you can't change the literal? So you can modify it. Otherwise you must copy it in a different buffer.

Comment: I need to work with two pointers ( with "s" is a tmp pointer to eliminate the symbol !

Comment: @W.draoui Well, but if you point to a string literal you can't do what you want....

Comment: I will use permenant later to respond user's query

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a look at

```
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
```

It returns the pointer to the first time that `needle` shows up in `haystack`. Just take the return pointer and write your replacement character to it.

PS: It is part of `<string.h>`

Comment: This is working to have '&acute;' position ( and thats working in my code too) but it dosen't work when i wan't to modify pointer value. i.e :
s=strstr(permenant,"&acute;");
*s='a'; -------> segmentation fault !!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your code has several issues which have been pointed out already.

To recap:

- You can't modify a string expressed like that, you need a character array.
- You should use `strstr()` to find sub-strings, not hand-written comparison chains.
- You should use `memmove()` to compact the string when doing the replacement.

Here's my attempt:

```
void replaceShorten(char *s, const char *what, const char *withWhat)
{
  char *hit;
  const size_t wLen = strlen(what);
  const size_t wwLen = strlen(withWhat);
  if(wwLen >= wLen)
    return;
  while((hit = strstr(s, what)) != NULL)
  {
    memcpy(hit, withWhat, wwLen);
    memmove(hit + wwLen, hit + wLen, strlen(hit + wLen) + 1);
    s = hit + wwLen;
  }
}
```

This is not optimized for maximum speed (it could use fewer calls to `strlen()`) but perhaps somewhat clear. It seems to work, when used like this:

```
char s[] = "Don&acute;t do it!";
replaceShorten(s, "&acute;", "'");
```

Note that it *must* shorten the string when doing the replacement, as the name implies. Arbitrary replacement is not supported.

Comment: I need to handwrite the comparaison because when i find the symbol "&acute:"  I need to modify s and permenant in the same time so if I use strstr i cant modify permenant by modifying s. please try to respond to the simple question :)

Comment: Of course you can modify an array by having a pointer point inside it. You can't (as has been said *many times now*, are you listening?) modify a string literal, regardless of how you access it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd break this down as follows:

- First, *don't* attempt to modify the input string; instead, write the converted string to a different buffer;
- Second, break your operations up into different functions - one to find the entity in the string, one to map the entity onto a replacement string, one to perform the replacement, etc;
- Third, use a lookup table or something instead of trying to match individual characters.

Here's a pass off the top of my head - it undoubtedly has some ugly bugs, but it should give you a flavor of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/**
 * Create a structure to map an entity name onto a replacement string...
 */
struct entity_lookup {
   char *entity_name;
   char *replacement;
};

/**
 * ... and use that structure to build the lookup table
 */
static const struct entity_lookup lookup_table[] =  {
  { "acute", "'" },
  { "amp", "&" },
  { "apos", "'"},
  { "lt", "<" },
  { "gt", ">" },
  { "nbsp", " " },
  { NULL, NULL }
};

/**
 * Scan the input string for the next entity, which begins with the
 * character '&' and ends with ';' - if we don't find the trailing
 * ';', then we treat the '&' as a literal character.  Returns the location
 * of the first character of the entity name in the string.  
 */
char *getNextEntity( const char *str, char **start, size_t *len )
{
  *len = 0;
  *start = strchr( str, '&' );

  if ( *start )
  {
    *start = *start + 1; // we want the text *following* &
    const char *end = strchr( *start, ';' );
    if ( end )
    {
      *len = end - *start - 1;
    }
    else
    {
      *start = NULL;
      *len = 0;
    }
  }

  return *start;
 }

/**
 * Find the replacement string for the given entity name.  Since our lookup
 * table is so small, a linear search is just fine in this case.
 */
char *getEntityReplacement( const char *entity )
{
  const struct entity_lookup *entry = lookup_table;

  while ( entry->entity_name != NULL && strcmp( entity, entry->entity_name ) )
  {
    entry++;
  }

  return entry->replacement;
}

/**
 * Replace any and all entities in an input string.  This code tries
 * to avoid any buffer overflows, but it's not very pretty and I haven't
 * exercised it that well.  I'm sure I could come up with a more elegant
 * method, but I've spent enough time on this already.
 */
void replaceEntities( const char * restrict input, char * restrict output, size_t maxOutputLen )
{
  char *entityStart = NULL;
  size_t entityLen = 0;

  /**
   * Initially point to the beginning of the input string.
   */
  const char *current = input;

  /**
   * Initially write an empty string to the output buffer.
   */
  *output = 0;

  /**
   * Look for the next entity; if we find one, copy everything from
   * the current position in the input buffer up to (but not including) 
   * the first character of the entity; then we copy the replacement
   * for the entity to the output buffer.
   */
  while ( getNextEntity( current, &entityStart, &entityLen ) )
  {
    if ( strlen( output ) + entityStart - current - 1 <  maxOutputLen - 1 )
    {
      /**
       * Copy everything from the current position to the start of the
       * entity to the output buffer; for example, copy "Won" to 
       * the output.
       */
      strncat( output, current, entityStart - current - 1 );

      /**
       * Find the entity in the lookup table.
       */
      char entityText[20] = {0};
      strncpy( entityText, entityStart, entityLen + 1 );

      char *repl = getEntityReplacement( entityText );

      /**
       * If there's a match and there's room in the output buffer,
       * write the replacement text to the output buffer, e.g., "'"
       */
      if ( repl && strlen( output ) + strlen( repl ) < maxOutputLen - 1 )
        strcat( output, repl );
      else
      {
        output[maxOutputLen] = 0;
        return;
      }
      current = entityStart + entityLen + 2;
    }
    else
    {
      output[maxOutputLen] = 0;
      return;
    }
  }

  /**
   * If we don't find any more entities, write the remainder of the input
   * string to the output buffer, e.g., "t Get Fooled Again"
   */
  if ( strlen( output ) + strlen( current ) < maxOutputLen - 1 )
    strcat( output, current );
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  char output[128];

  replaceEntities( argv[1], output, sizeof output );

  printf( "Original: %s\n", argv[1] );
  printf( "Stripped: %s\n", output );

  return 0;
}
```

As always, the proof is in the pudding - here are some example runs:

```
$ ./entities "Won&acute;t Get Fooled Again"
Original: Won&acute;t Get Fooled Again
Stripped: Won't Get Fooled Again

$ ./entities "Won&acute;t&nbsp;Get&nbsp;Fooled&nbsp;Again"
Original: Won&acute;t&nbsp;Get&nbsp;Fooled&nbsp;Again
Stripped: Won't Get Fooled Again

$ ./entities "Black &amp; Blue"
Original: Black &amp; Blue
Stripped: Black & Blue

$ ./entities "Black & Blue"
Original: Black & Blue
Stripped: Black & Blue

$ ./entities "#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;"
Original: #include &lt;stdio.h&gt;
Stripped: #include <stdio.h>
```

This code is too fragile for production use, but again, it should give you some ideas.